# syntax highlighting is not happening when I am writing "<!-- language: html -->"

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

I am having syntax highlighting problem in one of my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21959661/2767755).

While I write `<!-- language: lang-or-tag-here -->` syntax highlighting happened with the `html` part, but if I write `<!-- language: html -->`, then it is not happening.

Can anyone tell me why such is happening ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`<!-- language: html -->` tells the syntax highlighter to use the syntax highlighter associated with the [html](/questions/tagged/html) tag. Counterintuitively, this is not the HTML syntax highlighter. Because HTML posts often include CSS, the "default" less-specific highlighter is used instead.

To specify the HTML syntax highlighter explicitly, instead of referring to a tag, use the syntax:

```
<!-- language: lang-html -->
```

Comment: Hum..Great answer. :-)

Comment: why not the same happening here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21957190/how-to-wrap-nokogiri-nodeset-in-one-span/21957280#21957280 ?

Comment: @psubsee2003 This `<!-- language: lang-html -->`, should work right as here the answer suggests.

Comment: Wow.  How does someone know such a thing?  That is some very specific knowledge.

Comment: I am talking about the question linked here in the comment. I went to fix the same [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21957190/2767755). But found someone already did it. But syntax highlighting not happening there.

Comment: @psubsee2003 My bad.. sorry - here is the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21957190/2767755).

Comment: @animuson I specified HTML highlight explicitly.. still not happening.

Comment: @animuson Check the history.. It was there.. By mistake I did a wrong edit and then rolled it back. I am not seeing it as *OK*. Did you?

Comment: @animuson Yes it was and it is.. :-) Now I got it.. Thanks ..